# Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker option on a custom script

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I need to add some options to my datepicker field, I follow the documentation but I need to work on a custom script and I need some help with javascript.

This is the script that I've

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group  col-md-6">
  <label for="name">StartDate</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="startdate" placeholder="Start Date" value="04/03/2018">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.form-group input[type=date]').each(function (idx, elt) {
    if (elt.type != 'date' || elt.hasAttribute('data-datepicker')) {
        elt.type = 'text';
        $(elt).datetimepicker($(elt).data('datepicker'));
    }
});
```

I try to add:

```
$(elt).datetimepicker({
    locale: 'it',
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});
```

to set format and locale but doesn't works.

This is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/iotivedo/qf5eopdr/6/

Comment: `elt.type != 'date' || elt.hasAttribute('data-datepicker')` is `false` for the provided HTML. Why are you using `$(elt).datetimepicker($(elt).data('datepicker'));`?

Comment: It's a piece of code of a large script (voyager laravel admin)

Answer (score 2):

Where your document you tried to read?

It seem like you did not follow **Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4 Docs**

See https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

You can try:

(HTML)

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

(JS)

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    locate: 'it'
});
```

To config your display format and locate.

Comment: 1) the OP is already using `moment-with-locales` in the linked fiddle, so this is not the issue; 2) flag the question as duplicate, instead of copy-pasting answer (please note that I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question).

Comment: @VincenzoC thanks for your remind me, I will edit my answer, I really did not know that **OP is already using moment-with-locales in the linked fiddle**